# Semantic ui react making a Segment the same height

Tags: css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

The image enclosed shows the current state of the `Segment`. Is there a way to make them the same height?

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Segment, Header, Image, Card, Icon, Button, Divider, Radio, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import './UserAccountProfilePage.css';

export default function UserAccountProfilePage() {
  return (
    <Grid columns={2} stackable className="fill-content">
      <Grid.Column width={1} />
      <Grid.Column width={7}>
        <Segment>
          <Header as="h1">Profile</Header>
          <Image className="centered" src="/images/daniel.jpg" size="medium" circular />
          <Card fluid>
            <Card.Content>
              <Card.Header>Daniel</Card.Header>
              <Card.Meta>Joined in 2016</Card.Meta>
              <Card.Description>Daniel is a comedian living in Nashville.</Card.Description>
            </Card.Content>
            <Card.Content extra>
              <a>
                <Icon name="user" />
                10 Friends
              </a>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column width={7}>
        <Segment>
          <Header as="h2">Settings</Header>
          <Button positive fluid>
            Sync Google Calendar
          </Button>
          <Divider />
          <Header as="h4">Text notifications</Header>

          <Radio toggle />
          <Divider />
          <Header as="h4">Customize text notifications</Header>
          <RadioExampleRadioGroup />
        </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column width={1} />
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be challenging to achieve this in JSX specially when you have them in separate grids. I would instead give the segments fixed height via CSS.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to look at here. First, you need to add a `Grid.Row` component in between your `Grid` component and `Grid.Column` components. Then you need to add a `stretched` prop to it.

Add this: `<Grid.Row stretched>`

Luckily, the styles for this are already part of Semantic UI CSS.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Segment, Header, Image, Card, Icon, Button, Divider, Radio, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import './UserAccountProfilePage.css';

export default function UserAccountProfilePage() {
  return (
    <Grid columns={2} stackable className="fill-content">
      <Grid.Row stretched>
        <Grid.Column width={1} />
        <Grid.Column width={7}>
          <Segment>
            <Header as="h1">Profile</Header>
            <Image className="centered" src="/images/daniel.jpg" size="medium" circular />
            <Card fluid>
              <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>Daniel</Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>Joined in 2016</Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description>Daniel is a comedian living in Nashville.</Card.Description>
              </Card.Content>
              <Card.Content extra>
                <a>
                  <Icon name="user" />
                  10 Friends
                </a>
              </Card.Content>
            </Card>
          </Segment>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={7}>
          <Segment>
            <Header as="h2">Settings</Header>
            <Button positive fluid>
              Sync Google Calendar
            </Button>
            <Divider />
            <Header as="h4">Text notifications</Header>

            <Radio toggle />
            <Divider />
            <Header as="h4">Customize text notifications</Header>
            <RadioExampleRadioGroup />
          </Segment>
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={1} />
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```